# Get current marker location form GPS and save to mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, geolocation, gps

I have following JS code, form this code i need to set default location to my current GPS location,

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    zoom: 1,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.137879, -82.836914),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoom: 20
});

var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.651968, 9.478485),
    draggable: true
});


google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'dragend', function (evt) {
    document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = '<p>Marker dropped: Current Lat: ' + evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(3) + ' Current Lng: ' + evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(3) + '</p>';
});

google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'dragstart', function (evt) {
    document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = '<p>Currently dragging marker...</p>';
});

map.setCenter(myMarker.position);
myMarker.setMap(map);
```

and after setup my marker (if i need to change location), then i need a button to submit, after submit button it will save to my MySQL database.
Anyone can help on this?

Comment: what's the code of your backend?

Comment: @Jerry Chin, when my JS code or page load then it will show my default location, currently its not showing my current location, its showing pre-defined location

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ajax  call for posting the data to the server and then server side provide for store di values in database

Assuming that you have a server program for store the data named your_action_on_server.php you could extend your drag end event
this is only the sending part  (you must provide the server side  store function related  toy your db connection)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'dragend', function (evt) {
    document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = '<p>Marker dropped: Current Lat: ' + evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(3) + ' Current Lng: ' + evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(3) + '</p>';
    $.post( 'your_action_on_server.php', { 
                   lat:evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(3),
                  lng: evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(3)                  
                },
                      function (data) { 
                      // you code for succcess from server
          });
  });
```

For get the current location you could use  the The geolocation object api
see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation for more

```
  if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
    /* geolocation is available */
  } else {
    /* geolocation IS NOT available */
  }
```

.....

```
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    do_something(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  });
```

Comment: by default its not showing current location, would you please help me, when page load then it will load current location and then i can change marker, after that i can press a button to add then it will save that location.

Comment: For get current location you could use the javascript gelocaltion api .. i have update the answer  with a brief suggestion